# Google Chrome extension to run javascript code snippets instead using bookmarklets

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, javascript, bookmarklet

I have a lot of bookmarklets that I use frequently.

Currently I use my bookmark bar, which is filled up a little but, also you can't add icons, so the titles are mostly kept short.

Are there any good extensions for running javascript code directly with less effort as possible? The best way would be a keyboard shortcut, maybe?

*if there is no solution, I will have to code myself something small ;)*

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

There is a Chrome extension called [Shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck?hl=en) that may be what you're looking for. It lets you, among other things, map custom JavaScript snippets to keyboard shortcuts. It looks like you need to pay for it if you download it from the chrome web store.

Here is the [Github Project for Shortkeys](https://github.com/mikecrittenden/shortkeys) for the source code and documentation.

I work as a web developer and at one point I made a snippet that changes the border of all div elements to be 1px solid black so I can make sure everything was laid out properly. I've even used it in the past to open every link on the current page in its own tab. (Sounds crazy but there was a specific need for that at the time).

Basically, if you can write it in JavaScript, this extension lets you assign it to a keyboard combination and use it in the wild. It does other things too but this ability to run custom JavaScript was the most important to me.